# How to know which ports are listened by certain PID?

Tags: networking, osx, bsd

I have a PID of certain process listening some port(s) on my OS X and I need to know which port(s) is listened by this process. How can I do it?

I know I can use `lsof` to know which process is listening some port, but I need to perform an inverse operation.

Thank you.

**UPD**

OS X uses BSD utils, so I have BSD `netstat` not Linux `netstat`. Linux `netstat` has `-p` option to show PIDs, **BSD `netstat` uses `-p` to specify port and has no option to show PID.**

Comment: Do you mean to say that you're trying to find the ports a process is listening on? `netstat` can do this for you. You can `grep` on the PID if you want to filter the output of `netstat`

Comment: also `lsof` usage is not only one way. you can do something like `lsof|grep ${PID}`. which will crudely dump everything and `grep` will pick the lines with PID in them. In an off chance, it might list an irrelevant line, due to the PID number mistakenly matching some other value but chances are slim to none

Comment: @Dave, yes, you follow me right. Alack, as I can see, BSD version of `netstat` cannot display PIDs.

Comment: @MelBurslan it doesn't look like neat solution. Moreover it is not fast — it takes some time on my MBP.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found a solution on my own by deep reading `man lsof`. (Yes, RT*M still helps.) Thanks @Gilles for aiming.

**Here is the solution:** `lsof -aPi -p 555` (555 is the PID).

Explanation:

1. `-p` to specify the PID number;
2. `-i` to display only network devices;
3. `-a` to AND two conditions above (otherwise they will be ORed);
4. `-P` to display port numbers (instead port names by default).

Additionally, one can use `lsof -aPi4 -p 555` or `lsof -aPi6 -p 55` for IPv4 or IP6 only addresses accordingly.

If output will be parsed by another program `-Fn` option may be helpful. With this option `lsof` will produce "output for other program" instead of nice formatted output. `lsof -aPi4 -Fn -p 555` will output something like this:

```
p554
nlocalhost:4321
```

**PS**
All of it I've tested on my OS X El Capitan, but as I can see it should work on Linux too.

Answer (score 6):

[`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) provides information about files opened by processes, including network ports. It's available on pretty much all unix systems, [including OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html).

The [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) doesn't list any other tool for “match process to file or port” on OSX.

To list processes listening on a TCP port, you can use

```
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

`lsof -iUDP` lists processes that have a UDP socket open. `lsof -i` lists all open network sockets (TCP clients, TCP servers, and other IP protocols).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know which port is listening you can use netstat's -p option.you need to be the superuser:

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 80
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  125004/nginx
```

if you want to know more about it try this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/)

Comment: It's about GNU `netstat`, I have OS X and therefore use BSD `netstat`. It uses `-p` to specify TCP/IP port, And it has not option to display PID.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, you can use `sockstat` for this information. I am not sure whether OS X has `sockstat`, as I don't have a Mac.

For instance, to see all of the TCPv4 connections:

`sockstat -4`

Comment: Alack, there is not `sockstat` command on my Mac. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate netstat with grep, awk and sed to show ports with their corresponding pids on Linux & Cygwin:

```
$ netstat -ano | grep LISTENING | grep -v ‘\[::\]’ | sort -n | uniq -c | awk ‘ {print $3 “\t” $6}’ | sed ‘s/.*://’
```

[More details](https://automateandtroubleshoot.000webhostapp.com/2019/12/how-to-show-ports-listening-for-specific-pids-on-cygwin-and-linux)